# no matches for kind "configmap" in version "apps/v1"

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

Well, I'm using `minikube v1.26.0` and `kubectl` to manage `Kubernetes` on my local machine, when I decide to create a `ConfigMap` with `kubectl apply -f ConfigMapFile.yaml` I'm getting error `no matches for kind "configmap" in version "apps/v1"`

ConfigMapFile.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 
kind: ConfigMap 
metadata:
  name: test-config-map 

data:
   .........
```

Seems Like `ConfigMap` is not allowed or deprecated in Kubernetes `apps/v1`, but cannot find any solution or tips that would help me with this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use `apiVersion: v1` for configmap. You can also check the version of any resource using:

```
kubectl api-resources |grep -i configmap
configmaps                        cm           v1                                     true         ConfigMap
```